# Box shadow is not working when position is sticky

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I have applied position sticky to `th` and `td` in the example below. But when sticky is present in the class, the box shadow is not working.

Could some one let me know why?

```html
<div class="overflow-x-auto lg:overflow-visible">
  <div class="">
    <table class="border-collapse table-fixed w-[1000px] lg:table-auto lg:w-full border border-grey-200">
      <thead class="bg-grey-200">
        <th class="sticky left-0 top-0 p-4 z-10 shadow-grey w-[116px] lg:w-[140px] bg-grey-200"></th>
        <th class="p-4 align-middle text-body-30-m text-left" v-for="(header, headerIndex) in data.headerColumns" :key="headerIndex">
          {{ header }}
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="border border-b-grey-200" v-for="(row, rowIndex) in data.rows" :key="rowIndex">
          <td class="border border-r-grey-200 align-top" :class="
                  cell.icon
                    ? `grid p-4 justify-center border-0`
                    : cell.image
                    ? `text-center p-4 sticky left-0 shadow-grey bg-white z-10 w-[116px] lg:w-[140px] `
                    : cell.text
                    ? `text-left p-4 pr-8`
                    : `p-4`
                " v-for="(cell, cellIndex) in row.cells" :key="cellIndex">
            <div v-if="!cell.text && !cell.icon && cell.image && cell.link" class="grid grid-flow-row gap-3">
              <img :src="cell.image" :alt="cell.altText" />
              <span>{{ cell.link }}</span>
            </div>
            <span v-if="!cell.image && !cell.link && !cell.text"><smyths-icons
                    v-if="cell.icon"
                    :name="cell.icon"
                    size="24"
                    color="#008540"
                  ></smyths-icons
                ></span>
            <span v-if="!cell.image && !cell.link && !cell.icon">{{
                  cell.text
                }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Box shadow should work for evey position value. See [demo_with_sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/play?id=q0oejVqyyfaTIlM7CRlr5ThRisuub5YOBWpgX64Es4XV%2BtHTJ7Pz8IsSaLmL6taxfgpBciId0aja8Emb)

Comment: I tried this on my code and box-shadow work for any position I think it has another problem that I will say separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a shadow to an element in the Tailwind library you must add the `shadow` keyword in class like below :

```
<th class="sticky left-0 top-0 p-4 z-10 shadow shadow-grey w-[116px] lg:w-[140px] bg-grey-200"></th>
```